# NavigationLink selection issue inside a NavigationSplitView sidebar list

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink

I have a macOS/iOS application consisting of a three column NavigationSplitView. In the sidebar I have a list of 50-60 rows each one being a NavigationLink.

Selecting a row, scrolling until the selection is out of view then selecting a second row, when scrolling back to first selection, both rows appear as selected.

It seems like the list forgets to deselect the previous row. I don't remember seeing this issue before macOS 14.

[image: You can see it in action here]

The same thing happens also on Xcode preview.

Here is a code snippet of what I tried:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var selection: Int? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(selection: $selection) {
                ForEach(0...60, id: \.self) { item in
                    NavigationLink("Row \(item)", value: item)
                }
            }
        } content: {
            Text("Selected row is \(selection ?? 0)")
        } detail: {
            Text("Selected row is \(selection ?? 0)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like yet another SwiftUI bug to me.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Yes, I think you are right. I will file a bug report.